# Encoding and Decoding not working on Wordpress Comment

Tags: php, wordpress, encryption, comments

Am designing a wordpress captcha comment, in that I need to pass the value to verify with the entered value. So that I used input box to be hidden. So far worked good, after adding the encrypt and decrypt code shown below, the comment is not working properly. Actually the page is not loading fully. After getting captcha value its stopped and not loading the comment box, button and even sidebar.

```
function encrypt($bc_captcha_input_passing)
{
   return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, SALT, $bc_captcha_input_passing, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
}
function decrypt($bc_captcha_input_passing)
{
   return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, SALT, base64_decode($bc_captcha_input_passing), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)));
}
```

Am passing the value like this, and i tried

Method 1:

```
$bc_captcha_input_passing_value=encrypt($bc_captcha_input_passing);

echo '<input type="hidden" name="bc_captcha_req_value" value="' .
esc_attr($bc_captcha_input_passing_value ) . '">';
```

Method 2:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="bc_captcha_req_value" value="' .
esc_attr(encrypt($bc_captcha_input_passing_value )) . '">';
```

Method 3:

```
 echo '<input type="hidden" name="bc_captcha_req_value" value="' .
 encrypt($bc_captcha_input_passing_value ) . '">';
```

None of the method didn't work. Kindly suggest me.

Note: This code is working perfectly in Localhost. I can see the encrypted text in sourcecode and perfectly decoded it and produce the perfect result. But when I use in real time, the page is not loading properly as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is, Do you have the same configuration for your production environment? For example, Did you install the php-mcrypt module?